# DART await async function

Tags: dart, async-await

I have a button that launches 2 asynchronous functions
But the program does not wait for the completion of the first function, and immediately executes the second
I'm a beginner, and apparently I don't understand simple things. Where is my error? :(

```
  Widget wgCheckUpdate(){
    if (!isUpdated) {
      return
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await fnUpdateData(); //1st func
            await _updateUI();    //2nd func
          },
          child: const Text('Download'),
        );
    }
    return Container();
  }

fnUpdateData() async{
  final DbHelper dbh = DbHelper();
  var DB = await dbh.db;

  const String url = 'www.mysite.com';
  String path = '';
  var hStat, hResp;
  int i;

  List<dynamic> lRows = [];
  MapEvents ME;
  MapTagList TL;

  path = '/br/BcGetEvents.php';
  Uri webaddr = Uri.http(url, path);

  http.get(webaddr).then((response) async {
    hStat = response.statusCode;
    hResp = response.body;

    lRows = jsonDecode(hResp);

    if (lRows.isNotEmpty) {
      await dbh.fnClearTable('tsmBcEvents');
    }

    for (i = 0; i < lRows.length; i++) {
      ME = MapEvents.fromMap(lRows[i]);
      DB.insert('tsmBcEvents', ME.toMap());
    }

  }).catchError((error){
    hStat = -1;
    hResp = error.toString();
  });

  path = '/br/BcGetTagList.php';
  webaddr = Uri.http(url, path);

  http.get(webaddr).then((response) async {
    hStat = response.statusCode;
    hResp = response.body;

    lRows = jsonDecode(hResp);

    if (lRows.isNotEmpty) {
      await dbh.fnClearTable('tsmBcTagList');
    }

    for (i = 0; i < lRows.length; i++) {
      TL = MapTagList.fromMap(lRows[i]);
      DB.insert('tsmBcTagList', TL.toMap());
    }

    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('isUpdated', true);
  }).catchError((error){
    hStat = -1;
    hResp = error.toString();
  });
}
```

I tried to search in google and here... But, either I'm phrasing the question incorrectly, or I don't understand...
it says everywhere that it should work:
`void main() async { await firstFunction(); await secondFunction(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for your unexpected program flow is that you have a mix of using `await` and `then()`. That is not something I would recommend for most users since you will end up with confusing program execution.

E.g. `await` makes sure to "halt" your function from executing any further until the result of the `Future` are ready. But `then()` takes a callback which will be called later when the result are ready. This also means that `then()` does not have the same "halting" mechanic as `await` and that is why `fnUpdateData()` ends up finish its returning `Future` before everything inside the `fnUpdateData()` method are actually done running.

I have rewritten your `fnUpdateData()` to no longer make use of `then()`:

```dart
Future<void> fnUpdateData() async{
  final DbHelper dbh = DbHelper();
  var DB = await dbh.db;

  const String url = 'www.mysite.com';
  String path = '';
  var hStat, hResp;
  int i;

  List<dynamic> lRows = [];
  MapEvents ME;
  MapTagList TL;

  path = '/br/BcGetEvents.php';
  Uri webaddr = Uri.http(url, path);

  try {
    final response = await http.get(webaddr);

    hStat = response.statusCode;
    hResp = response.body;

    lRows = jsonDecode(hResp);

    if (lRows.isNotEmpty) {
      await dbh.fnClearTable('tsmBcEvents');
    }

    for (i = 0; i < lRows.length; i++) {
      ME = MapEvents.fromMap(lRows[i]);
      DB.insert('tsmBcEvents', ME.toMap());
    }

  } catch (error) {
    hStat = -1;
    hResp = error.toString();
  }

  path = '/br/BcGetTagList.php';
  webaddr = Uri.http(url, path);

  try {
    final response = await http.get(webaddr);

    hStat = response.statusCode;
    hResp = response.body;

    lRows = jsonDecode(hResp);

    if (lRows.isNotEmpty) {
      await dbh.fnClearTable('tsmBcTagList');
    }

    for (i = 0; i < lRows.length; i++) {
      TL = MapTagList.fromMap(lRows[i]);
      DB.insert('tsmBcTagList', TL.toMap());
    }

    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('isUpdated', true);
  } catch (error) {
    hStat = -1;
    hResp = error.toString();
  }
}
```

Some general advice you should consider:

- Do not have variables starting with cased letter. (e.g. `ME` and `TL` is not okay). Reason for this is that naming convention normally dictates that only types starts with cased letter.
- Don't declare all your variables at the beginning of your methods. Just declare them when you have a value for them. This also makes it possible to limit the scope of variables that is only used locally inside e.g. an if-statement. It is okay to declare a variable in the beginning if you need to use it in general for your method (e.g. to return something afterwards).
- Don't reuse variables for different purposes. This is also easier to prevent if you declare your variables closer to where you have the variable.

Comment: It works!!!! Thank you very much!! :) And doubly for the quick response!